# Is a GNOME3 fallback session without the panels possible on the LiveCD?

Tags: 11.10, gnome-fallback

Is a Gnome 3 fallback session without the panels, that doesn't  conflict with unity possible on a live CD?

On an installed system it works when I write a `*.session` in `/usr/share/gnome-session`.
But on a live CD that doesn't work, because Ubuntu will load Unity.

Why?

Answer (score 2):

Make a custom live iso using a tool like [Relinux](https://launchpad.net/relinux).
A helpful guide for using it is [Here](http://lkubuntu.wordpress.com/2011/10/10/relinux-a-way-to-create-a-bootable-iso-out-of-your-system/).
Configure your os as you see fit, add/remove apps and configure settings.  Then, to have those settings be used as default you need to copy them to /etc/skel but leave out any big files you don't need as to keep the iso size down below 4gb, or else it won't work.
In a terminal, run `sudo cp -r . /etc/skel/` then `gksu gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and make sure the line `user-session=` says the name of the session you want as default.  Then you can go ahead and follow the instructions for using Relinux

Comment: Thx for the answers .
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization is a good guide too.
The lightdm tip was really helpful.
Awn settings are only gconf values. =)

Answer (score 0):

The LiveCD doesn't include a GNOME3 or GNOME3 Fallback session, which is why it won't load it and it'll just fallback to Unity.

If you want a Live CD that does this you'll have to make a custom one with the session you want already installed on it.